React chrome extension chrome.tabs.sendMessage's response is undefined
Below is react chrome extension
I'm always using dev mode. At the very beginning when I load the extension in dev mode(using load unpacked), If i open the extension, I get chrome.tabs.sendMessage's response as undefined. Once I refresh, It works fine. If I change the url(file/component based routing in react/next) also, sometimes i get response as undefined. I'm unable to debug this issue.

Also, I want to execute same scrapeTab method in app.tsx either using background.js but i need to set data to htmlContent state, when scroll happens in the active tab(after scroll ends). I'd appreciate if anybody helps me...

App.tsx
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ScrapeMessages from './components/ScrapeMessages';
import { useRecoilState } from 'recoil';
import messagesState from './states/messages';
function App() {
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useRecoilState(messagesState);
  const scrapeTab = () => {
    if (chrome && chrome.runtime) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'getHTML' }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response) {
          setHtmlContent(response);
        } else {
          console.error('Error retrieving HTML content:', response);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.error(
        'Chrome API is not available. Make sure this component is running in a Chrome extension context.',
        chrome
      );
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    scrapeTab();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Slack scraper</h1>
{JSON.stringify(htmlContent)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

contentScript.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'getHTML') {
    const messages = scrapeTheDoc();
    sendResponse(messages);
  }
});
const scrapeTheDoc = () => {
  const container = document.querySelector('.p-workspace__primary_view_body');
  
  return container;
};

background.js
//this is an empty file

manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "web scraper",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Scraper",
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/logo.png",
    "32": "images/logo.png",
    "180": "images/logo.png",
    "192": "images/logo.png",
    "512": "images/logo.png"
  },
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "contextMenus", "tabs"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}


You can't send DOM elements. You can send JSON-compatible data like textContent or innerHTML. See also Accessing `window`/DOM/HTML of the webpage from the extension

@wOxxOm I havent pasted full code. I'm converting it to string and passing it to the react component. it's working fine if i refresh the tab. Only sometimes it returns undefined. I'm unable to recreate the error. But on consideration, at the very first time, when I load using 'load unpacked', at very first time when i try to open the extension, it returns undfined. If i close the extension and reload window then if i open the extension then it works fine

@wOxxOm , if i reload the extension in chrome://extensions/ and then if i try to open the extension at that time I'm getting response as undefined. If i close the extension then I refresh the tab and after that if I open the extension, then it's working fine


You need to re-inject content_scripts after reloading/installing the extension in Chrome. 2) chrome:// tabs can't run content scripts.


@wOxxOm after doing that(re injecting content_scripts), it's creating problems like,

permission issue
Chrome extension Insecure CSP value


You need to add "host_permissions":["<all_urls>"], but it's not an issue because you already request these permissions via content_scripts. As for CSP, it's not necessary to injection itself so it must be caused by something else in your code, which is not present in the question.

@wOxxOm I've already pasted all of my code

The posted code can't produce a CSP error, so there must be a problem either in html or in react config.

@wOxxOm , please check the updated code.
All I'm saying is, I'm getting error(Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-tu579CkybJdUvhuKm+Jzbw9D6VIRFZoepiMNcx95Jb8='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.)

The updated code cannot produce such an error, so the problem is react config that creates an inline script or uses eval() or creates a Function. I don't know how to configure react though.
